# Spring 2 to Spring 3 migration: one controller for multiple views

Tags: java, spring-mvc, migration, velocity

I'm working on migration from Spring 2.5.6 to Spring 3.2.11 and I stuck with one controller that is used by different views. This controller gets commandName value from a bean in servlet.xml file. Every bean has it's own commandName. Example:

```
<bean name="/dogs.zds" class="com.example.controller.MyController">
<property name="commandName" value="dogs"/>
</bean>
<bean name="/cats.zds" class="com.example.controller.MyController">
<property name="commandName" value="cats"/>
</bean>
```

The controller gets commandName value by this.getCommandName() in formBackingObject method and uses it to make a request to the database (dogs and cats are the names of the database tables).

For Spring 3 conversion I'm removing beans from servlet.xml because I use annotations. So now I don't know how can I pass/get commandName value if I remove those beans. We use Velocity so I cannot do  like in jsp. Also I don't want to use hidden fields.

Is there any way to achieve the same result I have with Spring 2.5 without modifying vsl pages and parsing urls?

Thanks

Comment: idk if that worked back in spring 3 but an `@Configuration` class in 4 can create multiple beans and you're free to call setters before returning: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html